# jQuery doesn't work in an object method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Given the example:

```
function Schedule (foo) {
    this.foo = foo;

    this.bar = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/something/',
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON"
        }).done (function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

It seems that `$.ajax()` does not fire from within the method context of this prototype method. I suspect this is a feature, not a bug. But, would like to avoid making this AJAX call manually (I'd rather use the jQuery method).

Is there a way to make this work? Or am I going to have to do it [the old fashioned way?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: I'm not sure but, with `url: "/something/" `, aren't you trying to to a get request on a folder?

Comment: Seems you cannot ask an honest question / get help on here with getting flamed / down voted.

Comment: Can you please post a little more? Where is the prototype in this code?

Comment: I am (perhaps) confused on the [definition of a prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype). Perhaps my question should have been worded: "jQuery doesn't work in object method?"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the $ (syntactic sugar) is what is breaking it.

Changing it to call jQuery "directly" fixes it:

```
function Schedule (foo) {
    this.foo = foo;

    this.bar = function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/something/',
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON"
        }).done (function(data){
            console.log(data);
    });
}
```

}

Comment: if you are trying on WordPress especially, it removes $ variable. Only accessible is jQuery.

Comment: No, it wasn't Wordpress. But, I appreciate the answer / thought.